# Missing $ inserted

Tags: equations

I've a new issues

```
\setlength{\parindent}{5 em} 
\begin{tabular}{rcll}\label{test}
$\omega \in \lim\limits_n \sup A_jn$ &(\Longleftrightarrow) & $\forall p, \exists n \ge p, 
\text{tel que } \omega \in A_n$ \\
  
 $&\Longleftrightarrow& \omega \text{ appartient à une infinité de } A_n$ \\
  
 &\Longleftrightarrow& $\sum\limits_n \textbf{1}_{A_n}(\omega) = + \infty$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668745/extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr#comment1662421_668745

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661975/tikz-3d-representation-of-the-gaussian-density-function#comment1646762_661975

Comment: as the full error message highlights you  have no `$` in `&(\Longleftrightarrow) &`  but why are you using `tabular` for a math display?

Comment: Off-topic: (a) should it be `A_jn` or `A_{jn}`? (b) Should it be `\lim\sup` or `\limsup`?

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using a `tabular` environment at all. Instead, do use either an `array` environment (which uses math mode automatically) or one of multi-row math environments -- such as the `alignat` environment -- provided by the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Either way, you won't be needing to type so many `$` tokens.

Here are two `array`-based solutions -- one uses inline-style math mode, the other display-style math mode -- and one `alignat*`-based solution. For the case at hand, one might say that the second and third solutions look very much alike. That is, of course, not coincidence. The second `array`-based solution is, overall, more straightforward to implement than the `alignat*`-based solution is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro and 'alignat*' environment

\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % col type for math operators
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} 
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcommand\myLongleftrightarrow{\hphantom{(}\mathrel{\Longleftrightarrow}\hphantom{)}}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % default value: 5pt
\begin{array}{rCl} % use 'array', not 'tabular'
\omega \in \lim_n \sup A_jn 
  & \mathrel{(\Longleftrightarrow)}
  & \forall p,\ \exists n \ge p \text{ tel que } \omega \in A_n\\
  & \Longleftrightarrow
  & \omega \text{ appartient à une infinité de } A_n \\
  & \Longleftrightarrow  
  & \sum_n \textbf{1}_{A_n}(\omega) = +\infty
\end{array}
\]

\bigskip
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}      % default value: 5pt
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}  % default value: 1.0
\begin{array}{RCL}               % use display-style math
\omega \in \smash[b]{\lim_n} \sup A_jn 
  & \mathrel{(\Longleftrightarrow)}
  & \forall p,\ \exists n \ge p \text{ tel que } \omega \in A_n\\
  & \Longleftrightarrow
  & \omega \text{ appartient à une infinité de } A_n \\
  & \Longleftrightarrow  
  & \sum_n \textbf{1}_{A_n}(\omega) = +\infty
\end{array}
\]

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\omega \in \smash[b]{\lim_n} \sup A_jn 
  & \mathrel{(\Longleftrightarrow)}
  &&\forall p,\ \exists n \ge p \text{ tel que } \omega \in A_n\\
  & \myLongleftrightarrow
  &&\omega \text{ appartient à une infinité de } A_n \\
  & \myLongleftrightarrow
  &&\smash[t]{\sum_n} \textbf{1}_{A_n}(\omega) = +\infty
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\mathbin` and not `\mathrel`?

Comment: @egreg - No good reason. :-) Fixed now.